# Significant increase in login time. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login

I experience a significant increase in login time on my Ubuntu 14.04.
I use an ssd drive, so booting to login screen lasts almost 9 seconds and login time was less than a second.
Suddenly after a reboot my login time increased to 30 seconds (I see a black screen with a cursor while my disk drive led is flashing like mad) After desktop is seen I can notice on my system-load indicator that my cpu was at 100% until all desktop components were loaded.
I created another user and login time was back to less than a second.
How could I resolve this? I have a lot of customized settings on my first user account.

EDIT:
I managed to have two concurrent Xservers running to monitor what was going on during the "slow" login. There were a lot of "apport-gtk" processes running with 11% cpu each so I uninstalled apport-gtk and the problem was solved. Login time dropped to less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% here but it sounds like you have a lot of installs/downloads under user and thus taking a longer time to boot

Comment: I think that if this was the problem I would be experiencing a gradual increase of login time.  In my case I went from a 1sec to a 30sec login time on a single reboot on a 3 months fresh installation.